# Pressing login_Click hangs the entire application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, forms, winforms

I was working on my c# winform application last night when my app stopped working. It even made my Visual Studio to stop working so I had to install Visual Studio on a separate PC. My problem is:

Whenever I press the login button, the application hangs, no warning, it just won't respond. Please see the image below

[Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGk5P.png)

I don't exactly know what caused the problem. Before that night everything was working well. I was working on a code that truncates a table but now the whole application won't launch. Here is the code for the Login button:

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //LOGIN
    {
        mainMenu mm = new mainMenu();
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;
        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected! Please fill up all the fields.");
            return;
        }
        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
        if (r)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome, admin!");
            mm.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Credentials.");
        }
    }
```

If the SQL query is necessary, here it is:

```
private bool validate_login(string user, string pass) //sql check
    {
        db_connection();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        cmd.Connection = connect;

        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now if I press the login button, the app won't work now. It won't proceed to the next form. I really cannot pinpoint where the problem is. I even tried reversing the code I did before it stopped working.

SQL is properly working and the tables exist. So I don't think the problem is with SQL.

I am really out of solution. I cannot make another project because this one is almost finished and I need to submit this 3rd week of November.

Comment: When you debug the app, on which line does the freezing occur?

Comment: @zaitsman whenever I press the login_Click, because I can press the exit button and the app will close.

Comment: It also hangs when I leave the two textbox empty.

Comment: let me rephrase, when you DEBUG and step through the code INSIDE `login_Click`, pressing F10, which of the lines INSIDE `validate_login` does this happen?

Comment: The freezing doesn't happen on validate_login. I stepped individually inside the login_Click and it freeze on `string user = textBox1.Text;` Sorry for the late reply. Was figuring it out im new into debugging

Comment: I also noticed that whenever I step into `mainMenu mm = new mainMenu();` the output window shows this message `The thread 0x1340 has exited with code 259 (0x103).`

Comment: Can u enable run time exception(alt+ctr+E->common language run time exception ) and check

Comment: @AbiTom Hello I checked the common language runtime exception but nothing happened.

Comment: I think I found what causes the freezing. I moved the code `mainMenu mm = new mainMenu();` at the beginning of Form1, and when I debugged the app, the login form Form1 now won't load! So I guess the mainMenu form is corrupted but I dont know why. And when I try to open the the design of mainMenu Visual Studio wont respond.

Comment: Will the question and the answer be useful for any user in future? If you think it will be useful, keep it, but if you think it was a problem that can not be reproduced anymore and the Q/A will not help future readers, delete it :)

Comment: I think the problem in connection so put your code in try catch block so it will throw an exception if your code has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following with the main menu.
In your Form1, ensure that it is set as follows outside the login_Click method:

```
mainMenu mm = null;
```

Then you do the following: in your login_Click method

```
if (r)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Welcome, admin!");
   mm = new mainMenu();
   mm.Show();
   this.Hide();
}
```

This should fix the problem you are having that Form1 does not want to work anymore